# Python - No JSON object could be decoded - only on VPS

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I'm making a python script for my VPS with this function:

```
def getHTTP(nick):
    param = urllib.urlencode({'@number': 12524, '@type': 'issue', '@action': 'show'})
    header ={"Accept": "text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2", "Content-Type": "application/json", "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36", "Host": "api.minecraft-italia.it"}
    connection = httplib.HTTPConnection("178.32.137.188")
    connection.request("GET", "/reward/29d225d8fcc434bddae959bbbcfa1d3d5184499e/" + nick, param, header)
    response = connection.getresponse()
    jresponse = response.read()
    output = json.loads(jresponse)['result']
    return output
```

Running this on my computer it works fine but running it on vps (debian 8), it gives me this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MCReward.py", line 113, in <module>
    init()
  File "MCReward.py", line 102, in init
    response = getHTTP(staffer)
  File "MCReward.py", line 63, in getHTTP
    output = json.loads(jresponse)['result']
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can your server actually access that IP? What happens when you ping it from there?

Comment: print jresponse, it's probably not a json like string

Comment: yes, it's a json and yes, i can acces that IP

Comment: @LoreSchaeffer well for me your code works, it returns: u"Username non presente su Minecraft ITALIA. L'hai cambiato? Visita la sezione Assistenza." since I don't have a valid username

Comment: @LoreSchaeffer can you provide a sample of your json

Comment: @YOBA This is the json {"result":"OK","list":[{"id_item":"264","name":"diamante","amount":"2"}]}